# Using IBAction to change Action of a different IBAction

Tags: objective-c, button, action

I have asked this question before but did not receive a response. So I am asking it again!

I have 4 radio buttons like this:

```
- (IBAction)optWine:(id)sender {
    ChangeLabel.text =  @"Hint: try a partial phrase such as 'cab' to find information on the single-vineyard cabernet's made at the Arcadian Winery";


}

- (IBAction)optWinery:(id)sender {

    ChangeLabel.text = @"Hint: try a phrase such as 'arc' to find the beautiful Arcadian Winery in Lompac, California.";

}


- (IBAction)optGrape:(id)sender {
    ChangeLabel.text = @"Hint: type partial phrases such as 'zin' for Zinfandel grape";

}

- (IBAction)optReview:(id)sender {
    ChangeLabel.text = @"Hint: try a partial phrase such as 'arc' to check-out reviews on wines by the Arcadian Winery";


}
```

... and I have 4 other action buttons like this:

```
- (IBAction)btnSearchWineries:(id)sender {

WineriesViewController *review = [[WineriesViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
review.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentViewController:review animated:YES completion:NULL];


}
- (IBAction)btnSearchGrapes:(id)sender {

GrapesViewController *review = [[GrapesViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
review.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentViewController:review animated:YES completion:NULL];



}
- (IBAction)btnSearchWines:(id)sender {
WinesViewController *review = [[WinesViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
review.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentViewController:review animated:YES completion:NULL];
}

- (IBAction)btnSearchReviews:(id)sender {
ReviewsViewController *review = [[ReviewsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
review.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentViewController:review animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

}

Depending on which of the radio buttons is pressed, I would like to change a single button to perform activates of one of the 4 search buttons. Something like this, but this does not work:

```
-(IBAction)btnSearch:(id)sender
{
switch (((UIButton *)sender).tag) {
    case 1:
    {

        WinesViewController *review = [[WinesViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        review.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
        [self presentViewController:review animated:YES completion:NULL];
        break;
    }

    case 2:
    {
        WineriesViewController *review = [[WineriesViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        review.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
        [self presentViewController:review animated:YES completion:NULL];
        break;
    }
        break;
    case 3:
    {
        GrapesViewController *review = [[GrapesViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        review.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
        [self presentViewController:review animated:YES completion:NULL];
        break;
    }
    case 4:
    {
        ReviewsViewController *review = [[ReviewsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        review.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
        [self presentViewController:review animated:YES completion:NULL];
        break;
    }

    default:
        break;
}
```

}

I assigned tags in IB and nothing happens. I also tried assigning tags to the individual buttons, nothing happens. I tried using strings with if statements, nothing happens.

Comment: It's difficult to tell what you are trying to achieve. If all you want is to push one of a few view controllers depending on user selection, there are much simpler ways to achieve that. Can you explain further just what you are trying to do?

Comment: -gerald- I can only have ONE search button (for various reasons) and I need it to CHANGE its action (open a different viewController) depending on which radio button is selected. This is a search engine. If a user selects (for instance) the third radio button, and types a search term, the "search" button will perform a completely different action than if the user selected the forth button.  After more testing, I am finding that I cannot cycle through the switches or the if statements via the radio buttons. So I think this is where the solution lies.

Comment: here is another way to look at it: you have 4 buttons that control the action of a 5th button. when you click on one of the first 4 buttons, it switches the function (action) of the the 5th button to do something, but the something HAS to be another action. so it would be like having 4 different IBACTION's inside of if statements or switches that are inside of another IBACTION and the switches/if statements are being controlled by 4 other IBActions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, here's how I would do this. Start by defining an enum like this:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, SearchType) {
    SearchTypeWine,
    SearchTypeWinery,
    SearchTypeGrapes,
    SearchTypeReviews
};
```

Give your controller a property like so:

```
@property (nonatomic) SearchType searchType;
```

Then you make 4 UIButtons. You can hook them all to the same IBAction to reduce LoC.

```
- (IBAction)buttonPresssed:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    switch (button.tag) {
        case 100:
            self.searchType = SearchTypeWine;
            break;
        case 101:
            self.searchType = SearchTypeWinery;
            break;
        case 102:
            self.searchType = SearchTypeReviews;
            break;
        case 103:
            self.searchType = SearchTypeGrapes;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Then the method for executing the search:

```
- (IBAction)performSearch:(id)sender
{
    switch (self.searchType) {
        case SearchTypeWine:
            //handle appropriately
            break;
        case SearchTypeWinery:
            //handle appropriately
            break;
        case SearchTypeReviews:
            //handle appropriately
            break;
        case SearchTypeGrapes:
            //handle appropriately
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: is SearchType a property? I put it in my .h file and it says Unknown property SearchType.

Comment: Yeah at the top of your interface file you need to put that NS_ENUM. Before @interface. Then when you declare the property the compiler will recognize SearchType

Comment: OK. Did that. No errors. But the switching is not switching. I put NSLogs in place of //handle appropriately and it only shows the first log. I think I hooked the buttons up correctly, but must have done something wrong.

Comment: Did you set your tags to the values in the switch?

Comment: Sorry, I think this is problem all along. I don't know how to set/receive tag info. Can you give an example? Do I set the tag in the //handle appropriately?

Comment: Cool, now I feel stupid. Cause I did this before and do not like it. You have to set the tag in IB Attributes inspector and because my boss is old school I have been trying to learn to hard code everything, so I forgot... It works now. Thanks! Upvote.